# exponential/percentage based random number chooser

Tags: probability, exponential-function

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a function that will output a random number that is exponentially more likely to be closer to the input. You can assume i have a way to generate numbers in a range, but not based on any sort of exponential probability (ie. a flat chance for every number in the range). What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider having a function that follows a Gaussian distribution centered a 0. 
If you're familiar with the curve e^(-x^2), if you try to graph the function, it will look like such a curve. Taking the integral from a certain point (p-value) will give you probability.